# PHP parent database class not found in it's child class

Tags: php

I keep getting this error and I have no idea why:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'db' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Login-system-oop\commands.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Login-system-oop\index.php(9): include() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login-system-oop\commands.php on line 2

My code:
**db.php**

```
<?php
class db {
private $server;
private $usern;
private $pass;
private $database;

protected function connect() {
  $this->server = "localhost";
  $this->usern = "root";
  $this->pass = "";
  $this->database = "logsysdboop";

  $conn = new mysqli($this->server, $this->usern, $this->pass, $this->database);
  return $conn;
  }
}
?>
```

**commands.php**

```
<?php
class commands extends db  {
public function display() {
  $sql = "Select * from users";
  $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  foreach ($datas as $data) {
    echo $data['user']."<br>";
   }
  }
 }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'commands.php';
$obj = new commands;
$obj->display();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You also need to include the db.php file as well (although I prefer `require_once 'db.php'`).

Answer (score 0):

As *Nigel Ren* already suggested, you need to import the class at the top of your PHP script with one of the methods:

- **`require_once __DIR__ . '/db.php';`**
- `require __DIR__ . '/db.php';`
- `include_once __DIR__ . '/db.php';`
- `include __DIR__ . '/db.php';`
- `use db;`

And also, once that is fixed change `$datas` to `$data` (because `$datas` seems to be a typo and is never defined), like below in your `commands.php` file:

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

class commands extends db  {
public function display() {
  $sql = "Select * from users";
  $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  foreach ($data as $entery) {
    echo $entery['user']."<br>";
   }
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use 
    require_once("db.php"); 
in commands.php
before extending db class. Further you are storing data into     $data array and trying to retrieve it from     $datas in the loop which is again not defined.

correct the above , I think your code will be fine.